# Silverlight Test project - found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly

Tags: silverlight, build, msbuild, castle-windsor, moq

I have a Silverlight project and i use `Castle Windsor 3.2` as my `DI container`.
My test project is a `Silverlight class library` and i use `Moq` to mock out my interfaces.

`Moq` is dependant on a reference to `Castle Core 2.5`.  No problem so far, my application works fine with the 3.2 version and my tests run ok with the 2.5 verion.
Altough a warning is generated: `found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly`.
Still everything is working as it should.

Now for the deployment we use CruiseControl and it is configured to treat this warning as an error and my build fails for deployment.

I allready tried of `Moq` works witht he new version of `Castle.Core` But unfortunatly it doesn't.

I seem to be unable to add a redirection cause my `Silverlight` test project doesn't take an app.config file.

When adding the `<NoWarn>` section to my vb.proj file the warnings dissapear when building my Solution.  But `CruiseControl` uses `MSBuild` and it doens't recognize the warning numbers.

Any suggestions how to fix this issue?

Comment: there is no Windsor 3.5, the latest version is 3.2

Comment: indeed, missed there, but i think my point is clear ;)